# Quotes/ Hints page for Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, feature-request, answers

Over the time I have been on SO, I have found many questions and answers that I believe to be gems. Some of them include quotes and hints for better Program Development.

It just crossed my mind to have a hints/ quotes page by harnessing data from such gemstone questions and compiling them into a single database.

Is it possible/ feasible?

NB: This is only a suggestion and I just felt like sharing it.

---

**EDIT:**

Here's how it might work :

The first thing is that it won't only be limited to questions (i.e. it may include answers or parts of answers as well).

Selection of the questions can be done on a voting to select basis just like voting to delete or close a question (but only after nomination by a person does that text become eligible for voting).

Then a moderator can check it out. Presenting them can be done on a special page or blog like "Quotes from Stack Overflow". Tags can be added once the number of posts on the page exceed a particular limit.

Comment: How would that work exactly? Who would select the questions? How would they be presented? One "list of all gems" per tag? (i.e. I think your suggestion is a bit too vague.)

Comment: I have editted my post. Please check it out.

Answer (score 2):

Various sites do have a "Question of the Week" feature on their blogs - see ours at [security.blogoverflow.com](http://security.blogoverflow.com/category/question-of-the-week/) which does sort of what you are asking. Our community nominates and votes on which ones they want to get onto the blog.

This idea may work for you. I don't think trying to do it on the site itself will work, though - it doesn't really follow how SE works. If you want the highest voted ones, just search for by votes :-)

Comment: I understand that making it work will be tedious. Nevertheless, I have added a kind of a working model in my post. Just check it out.